# Give solution for paging with spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with paging, assume that I have list 7 items, so I want to get the first page with 3 items[1,2,3], and the second page will return items [3,4]. Problem is the item 3 in the first page has duplicated with the second page. So how I get the second page with items start from 4.

**This is my code:**

```
public ResponseEntity<List<ItemDTO>> getAllItems(
        @PageableDefault(sort = { SORT_ID }, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable
    ) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Items");
        Page<ItemDTO> page = itemService.findAll(pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }
```

Comment: Please give us some more information and show use your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting

Comment: @StefanGolubović the link is so simple, When size of the later page less than previous page It will contains item which has appear on previous page.